# How to anchor a specific data point of multiple lines and then link them by those points selected?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset like below, there are three key variables: ID, Year, and Value. And then, I use ggplot to run a plot (X = 1:nrow(df), Y = Value) like below. Different groups (i.e., ID) have different data points, for example, the group with ID = 1 has three data points. So, each group can have a line.

I was wondering if there is any way related to ggplot to help to select a specific data point of multiple lines and then link them by using that specific point selected? For instance, if selecting the first data point of each group, then Value = 10 for ID =1 and Value = 6 for ID =2 would be selected, and then can link and draw those groups by those specific data points selected.

And similar scenarios can also be set to select the middle data point or last data point of each group. But in the meantime, every data point of each group (line) would be kept and shown on that plot. Thank you very much.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works: It creates a variable that stores the row/observation position within each group of IDs, and then uses that position signal to create a new group that will be connected through `geom_path()`.
To help visualize it, the id variable is mapped to shapes (circles, triangles, squares).

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- 
  tibble(id    =   c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
       year  = sample(x = 2010L:2020L, size = 9, replace = TRUE),
       value = sample(x = 1:20, size =  9, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  arrange(id, year, -value)

df %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(row_position = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = value, group = row_position, colour = as.factor(row_position))) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = as.factor(id)), size = 3, alpha = 0.5) + 
  geom_path()
```

[image]